# HTTP Error 500.19 - 0x8007000d - web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a .net 2.1 core web app that is meant to be working locally in IIS however Im getting a 500.19 error. When I try to access any of the features of the website in IIS I get the error: there was an error while performing this operation. Can someone please help me on how to fix this? Thanks!

Chrome -

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       
Config File    \\?\C:\Development\adtool\trunk\AD Tool\web.config
Requested URL      http://adtool.local:80/
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
```

web.config -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" stdoutLogEnabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is this firs time you are deploying dot.net core app on this IIS? This error code is mostly when the hosting environment doesn't have required core packages installed.

Comment: Yes its the first time,I have installed .net core module and URLrewrite (not specified in web.config).

Comment: install: Microsoft .NET Core <version> - Windows Server Hosting`. Details given in answer below

Answer (score 1):

as discussed above, you need to install .net core packages. For example, I'll share my case, where I configured server for .net core 2.2.3. It should look like:

[image]

And set app pool as:

`.NET CLR Version` - set value to '*No Managed Code*'

`Managed pipline mode` - set value to '*Integrated*'

Let me know if you still face issues.

Comment: Now Im getting Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModule" in its module list

Comment: I can access the icons in IIS now but the ASP.NET panel is missing, any ideas?

Comment: Ok so now I can see ASP.NET panel as I recreated the website in IIS but Im still getting above error

Comment: do you mean, you are getting same errors? Which packages did you install?